# How to make this html code and css be in mobile app?

Tags: html, css

This is my html and css that I started, sorry for bad edit. I really want to know how to make a mobile app.
**What is the code that I should add to have a mobile size app 
when open in web that I don't need to resize it?
Then what can I do to make it responsive in css?
Thanks **

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
 width: 960px;
}
.wrapper{
 text-align: center;
 width: 99%;
 position: absolute;
}
.header{
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

.header img {
 width: 360px;
}

#nav {
 background-color: black;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 1em;
 border-top-width: medium;
 border-top-style: groove;
 border-bottom-style: groove;
 border-bottom-width: medium;
}
#nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 display: block;
 font-size: larger;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li a {
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 position: relative;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #1E5BD4;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#nav ul li a.active {
 text-decoration:underline;
 color: #EDF0BA;  
}
.how, .about{
 font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
 margin-left: 10%;
 margin-right: 10%;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: left;
 color: black;
}
.sectiontitle{
 text-align: center;
 color: black;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #767676;
}
.footer{
 background-color: black;
 width: 100%;
 border-style: groove hidden hidden;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
 padding-top: 1%;
 padding-bottom: 1%;
 font-size: 1em;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-variant: small-caps;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.addnotes {
 float: left;
 padding-left: 2%;
 font-color: black;
}

.listnotes {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}

.listnotes li {
 background: url('noteicon.png') no-repeat;
 width: 220px;
 height: 135px;
 margin-left: 45%;
 padding-top: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.noteTitle { 
 float: left;
 padding-left: 2%;
 color: black;
}

.createcontent {
 float: right;
 padding-right: 25%;
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.definition {
 padding-top: 10%;
}

.enumeration {
 padding-top: 15%;
}

#titletextbox {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header" id="header">
    <div class="logo"> <img src = "logo.png" alt = "logo" name = "logo" id = "logo"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="navigation" id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class='active'><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="notes.html"><span>Notes</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="exam.html"><span>Exams</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <span class="divider"></span>
  <div class="homecontent">
    <h2 class="sectiontitle">About Test Your Notes!:</h2>
    <section class="about">
    TestYourNotes is a web application that will surely help students 
 boost their scores for their quizzes and exams. 
 TestYourNotes lets users take down notes with two different categories, 
 namely, Definition of Terms and Enumeration. 
 After saving their notes, they can easily review their notes through 
 the view function and also make a mock test/questionnaire as a reviewer 
 using the notes they have created to test their understanding 
 about what they&#146ve taken down through the Generate exam function.
    </section>
    <h2 class="sectiontitle">How To Use:</h2>
    <section class="how">
    <h3>To write notes</h3>
 <ul>
  <li> Navigate to the NOTES page </li>
  <li> Click add + a note </li>
  <li> Edit title of the note on the left side of the page </li>
  <li> Add an item depending on the category you want to add (Definition of terms and/or Enumeration)</li>
  <li> If you choose to add an item for Definition of terms category, click add 
    new item to define a term. Simply type the term you want to define and its definition.
    After adding all the terms you want, click save. </li>
  <li> If you choose to add an item for Enumeration, click add new Enumeration of items
    Simply type the classification of the items you will enumerate and type all the items
    of that classification. To add a new item for that classification just click enter. 
    After adding all the classification you want, click save. </li>
 </ul>
 <h3>To view notes</h3>
 <ul>
  <li>Click the view notes below the name and date of the notes you have saved.</li>
 </ul>
 <h3>To generate an exam for a note</h3>
 <ul>
  <li>Click the generate exam below the name and date of the notes you have saved.</li>
  <li>Upon clicking generate exam button, a dialog box will appear asking what
   you want to name your generated exam. Type the name you want and then 
   click generate</li>
 </ul>
 <h3>To answer an exam</h3>
 <ul>
  <li>Click the title of the exam you want to answer.</li>
  <li>After answering all the items simply click submit exam</li>
  <li>After clicking submit exam, your score will be shown immediately.</li>
 </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
   <h3 class="copyright">Copyright</h3>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a mobile app you need to create a mobile app using the programing language for whichever OS/device you choose. You can then use webviews to display web content within the app. Take a look at ide's for mobile app development as an easy start.

To create responsive websites that display nicely on mobile devices, use media queries. You can find relevant info all over the shop. Just do a [search for css @media queries](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20media%20queries&es_th=1).

An example of a basic media query is as follows:

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px){
/* mobile devices with a max screen width of 640px */
p{color:#f00;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with putting `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">` in your html code.

You can make the code responsive using `@media` in css. you can alternatively take help of css frameworks like bootstrap.